# Stripe CardElement not rendering

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am attempting to integrate Stripe into my application, but I am having issues getting the CardElement to render within my Payment Form.

Here is my code for my Payment Form:

```
import React from "react";
import { Typography, Button, Divider } from "@material-ui/core";
import {
  Elements,
  CardElement,
  ElementsConsumer,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

import Review from "./Review";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY);

console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY);

const PaymentForm = ({
  checkoutToken,
  nextStep,
  backStep,
  shippingData,
  onCaptureCheckout,
}) => {
  const handleSubmit = async (event, elements, stripe) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) return;

    const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);

    const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: "card",
      card: cardElement,
    });

    console.log("[Payment Method]", paymentMethod);

    if (error) {
      console.log("[error]", error);
    } else {
      const orderData = {
        line_items: checkoutToken.live.line_items,
        customer: {
          firstname: shippingData.firstName,
          lastname: shippingData.lastName,
          email: shippingData.email,
        },
        shipping: {
          name: "International",
          street: shippingData.address1,
          town_city: shippingData.city,
          county_state: shippingData.shippingSubdivision,
          postal_zip_code: shippingData.zip,
          country: shippingData.shippingCountry,
        },
        fulfillment: { shipping_method: shippingData.shippingOption },
        payment: {
          gateway: "stripe",
          stripe: {
            payment_method_id: paymentMethod.id,
          },
        },
      };

      onCaptureCheckout(checkoutToken.id, orderData);

      nextStep();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Review checkoutToken={checkoutToken} />
      <Divider />
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom style={{ margin: "20px 0" }}>
        Payment method
      </Typography>
      <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        <ElementsConsumer>
          {({ elements, stripe }) => (
            <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e, elements, stripe)}>
              <CardElement />
              <br /> <br />
              <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                <Button variant="outlined" onClick={backStep}>
                  Back
                </Button>
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  variant="contained"
                  disabled={!stripe}
                  color="primary"
                >
                  Pay {checkoutToken.live.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol}
                </Button>
              </div>
            </form>
          )}
        </ElementsConsumer>
      </Elements>
    </>
  );
};

export default PaymentForm;
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEwAR.png) is an image of the payment form as it stands now. Note that the CardElement is not present.

I do not get any error messages in the console related to Stripe or anything that would indicate something wrong. I have even given the CardElement a class name and checked it within the Inspector and found that it exists, but as an empty Div. Following that, I took a look at Stripe's documentation on the matter, but it would seem that I have followed everything correctly.

If someone might know what's up and can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue. Apparently `loadStripe()` resolves `null` in a server environment. And since I was running a local server for my application, it returned null and thus my `CardElement` did not render. After deploying the app to AWS, it now works as intended.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 3):

`loadStripe()` is an asynch function that returns a promise. It is noted in the props section of the [ElementsConsumer docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#elements-consumer) that:

"Note that if you pass a Promise to the Elements provider and the Promise has not yet resolved, then stripe and elements will be null."

In your code above your promise is not resolving before your component renders which is leading to the above returning null and your CardElement not mounting.

To fix this it is recommended that you call `loadStripe()` and wrap your `PaymentForm` component within the `Elements` provider at the root of your app as opposed to within your `PaymentForm` component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a bit confused though. When you say "root of your app", are you referring to where my PaymentForm component is called? Or where the App component is called (i.e index.js)? I apologize as I am a bit new to this.

Comment: The root will generally be the top level component of your app. So in your case it sounds like you are rendering your App component in index.js so your "root" would be your App component and you would wrap App within <Elements /> so that the Elements provider is accessible anywhere you need it. 

Alternatively, you can just wrap your PaymentForm component if you aren't using Elements anywhere else in your app.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. In any case, I finally figured out the issue. Thanks for your help!